# Change Display of Column Name in DetailsView

Tags: c#, database, ado.net

I'm creating a page where a user can edit their user information. I'm using a DetailsView control in ASP to display the data. How do I change the names of the field e.g. "FirstName" display as "First Name"?

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sauceatronConnString" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sauceatronConnString %>"
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sauceatronConnString.providerName %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT FirstName, LastName, ShipAddress, ShipCity, ShipState, ShipZipCode, ShipCountry, Phone, Email, Pwd, BillAddress, BillCity, BillState, BillZipCode, BillCountry FROM [Customers]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Customers] SET [Firstname] = @Firstname, 
        [Lastname] = @Lastname, [Age] = @Age, 
        [IsFullTime] = @IsFullTime, [Username] = @Username, [Password] = @Password"></asp:SqlDataSource>



        <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" DataSourceId="sauceatronConnString" AutoGenerateRows="true" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" />

        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="CustomerID" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="ContactName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ShipAddress" HeaderText="ContactTitle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ShipCity" HeaderText="CompanyName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ShipZipCode" HeaderText="Address" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ShipCountry" HeaderText="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Region" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="PostalCode" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Pwd" HeaderText="Country" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BillAddress" HeaderText="Phone" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BillCity" HeaderText="Fax" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BillState" HeaderText="Phone" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BillZipCode" HeaderText="Fax" />
        </Fields>

        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Firstname" Type="String"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Lastname" Type="String"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Age" Type="Int32"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="IsFullTime" Type="Boolean"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Password" Type="String"/>
        </UpdateParameters> 


        <asp:/DetailsView>


</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `AutoGenerateRows="false"` Since you have defined all the Fields in `DetailsView`

Now you can give meaningful names for the header text like below

Set the header text:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" ReadOnly="True" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="ShipAddress" HeaderText="Ship Address" />
```

Please follow some tutorials or books about ASP.NET. There are lot of places to fix in your aspx page markup, I have changed few but it will not work, you don't have where condition in your update command. if you edit then all the records will update in the database.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sauceatronConnString" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sauceatronConnString %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sauceatronConnString.providerName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT FirstName, LastName, ShipAddress, ShipCity, ShipState, ShipZipCode, ShipCountry, Phone, Email, Pwd, BillAddress, BillCity, BillState, BillZipCode, BillCountry FROM [Customers]"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Customers] SET [Firstname] = @Firstname, 
[Lastname] = @Lastname, [Age] = @Age, 
[IsFullTime] = @IsFullTime, [Username] = @Username, [Password] = @Password">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Firstname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Lastname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Age" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="IsFullTime" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="sauceatronConnString"
    AutoGenerateRows="false" AutoGenerateEditButton="True">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ShipAddress" HeaderText="Ship Address" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ShipCity" HeaderText="Ship City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ShipZipCode" HeaderText="Ship Zip Code" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ShipCountry" HeaderText="Ship Country" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Pwd" HeaderText="Pwd" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BillAddress" HeaderText="Bill Address" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BillCity" HeaderText="Bill City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BillState" HeaderText="Bill State" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BillZipCode" HeaderText="Bill Zip Code" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there something else I need to do to get that displayed on the page? I only see the edit link for that table.